# Modelo do Entity Framework e Classe de Dominio

Tags: entity-framework

A notação do Entity Framework é "muito poluída" se levar em conta como estou acostumado a definir as classes de Domínio, queria saber se é correto ter uma classe de modelo do EF para representar os dados do banco e uma para representar a classe de domínio.

Exemplo de classe de modelo do EF:

Classe Usuário

```
public class UsuarioDominio
{        
    public string Matricula { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }                
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Atividade> AtividadesResponsavel { get; set; }
}
```

Classe Atividade

```
public class Atividade
{        
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataInicio { get; set; }
    public string ResponsavelID { get; set; }
    public virtual UsuarioDominio Responsavel { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Exemplo de classe utilizado normalmente:

Classe Usuário

```
public class UsuarioDominio
{        
    public string Matricula { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }                
    public string Login { get; set; }
}
```

Classe Atividade

```
public class Atividade
{        
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataInicio { get; set; }
    public UsuarioDominio Responsavel { get; set; }
    public char Status { get; set; }
}
```

Pelo que entendi do EF a classe a qual será o "modelo para a tabela" deve ter as mesmas propriedades que a tabela como FK's(ResponsavelID), por exemplo. Além de ser necessário adicionar na outra classe o virtual List já que tem o relacionamento de 1 : N.

Estou aprendendo ainda e talvez esteja falando besteira, mas pelo que entendi é mais ou menos assim que funciona (Inclusive acho meio redundante ter o int ResponsavelID e o virtual UsuarioDominio Responsavel).

A pergunta é, utilizo a classe de Domínio como estou acostumado, utilizo apenas o modelo EF ou é possível usar os dois ? Aproveitando também, existe a possibilidade de usar só a de domínio e fazer os mapeamentos pelo Map de cada classe de modo que não polua o código da classe de Domínio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..., queria saber se é correto ter uma classe de modelo do EF para representar os dados do banco e uma para representar a classe de domínio.

É **incorreto**. Usando duas classes distintas, você trará para o sistema:

- Ambiguidade de objetos: o *Model* contém não apenas os dados e as relações entre outras entidades, mas também as regras de validação, tanto na apresentação quanto no servidor. Criando duas classes, o trabalho não apenas é inútil como pode criar comportamentos distintos no fluxo dos dados.
- ***Over-Engineering***: haverá um nível a mais de complexidade desnecessária, que apenas serve para aumentar o tempo de compilação, linkagem e uso de memória;
- Anti-padrão: A Microsoft não usa este tipo de arquitetura no modelo padrão de projetos publicados por ela. Não há motivo para você usar também.

> Estou aprendendo ainda e talvez esteja falando besteira, mas pelo que entendi é mais ou menos assim que funciona (Inclusive acho meio redundante ter o int ResponsavelID e o virtual UsuarioDominio Responsavel).

Não é. A ideia da definição do campo de dados de chave estrangeira permite você definir qual o tipo de dados da coluna, que não precisa ser necessariamente `int`.

> A pergunta é, utilizo a classe de Domínio como estou acostumado, utilizo apenas o modelo EF ou é possível usar os dois?

Use apenas o *Model* do Entity Framework.

> Aproveitando também, existe a possibilidade de usar só a de domínio e fazer os mapeamentos pelo Map de cada classe de modo que não polua o código da classe de Domínio?

Eu não entendi seu conceito de "poluição". A decoração de propriedades, classes e métodos é uma ferramenta poderosa para enriquecer o comportamento da sua aplicação de forma simples e sucinta.

Existir, existe a possibilidade, mas não existe motivo para isso, a não ser gerar prolixidade no seu desenvolvimento.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, não respondi antes, pois estava de férias kkkkk. Só tem uma parte que ainda não entendi muito bem, eu utilizo o public virtual para poder acessar as propriedades da tabela associada partir dali direto, certo ? Pois como falei eu colocando o ResponsavelID eu estou definindo a chave estrangeira, vai vir um int se eu acessar ele, enquanto no virtual acesso o "objeto" em si, correto? Nesse caso, eu preciso ter os dois visto que é necessário eu definir a chave estrangeira ou só deixando o virtual e mapeando como foreing key um atributo também é valido?

Answer (score 1):

É possível usar os dois, mas você teria que ficar convertendo um para o outro e isso geraria trabalho desnecessário.

Sim, é possível utilizar os mapeamentos de forma separada. Um exemplo seria:
http://netcoders.com.br/blog/mapeamento-com-entity-framework-code-first-fluent-api-parte-2/

Não sei se é porque eu estou acostumado com o Hibernate do Java, mas acho bem mais prático tudo junto em um lugar apenas.